# Google Sheets Custom Gauge Chart

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

Is it possible to use a cell value as the MIN/MAX values within a gauge chart? At the moment if I set the value so anything other than an integer value it gets cleared the sec I move away from the input field.

[image: Google Sheets Custom Gauage Chart]

I've looked into other customization options but all the documentation for coding custom values for charts seems to be when using the draw api on a custom app or webpage. In this instance I'm just trying to customize and embed the charts within the current working spreadsheet.

Appreciate any help or insight the community may have cause my searching is returning NULL.

Comment: Please show your code, and describe what particular input you want to be rendered in the gauge chart.

Comment: I have no code, don't know how to code in Google sheets, but I now how to make formulas, and I would like a simple formula in the gauge ranges just like I showed in the picture. If there is something more to this (code-wise) I'm unaware of it

Comment: I tried to solve your problem, but I was not even able to access the gauge chart programmatically. As I found out, using barely Google Spreadsheets, it's impossible: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79450/how-to-access-a-gauge-chart-in-google-spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

No. Try and enter anything other than a number and a warning message appears:

> Must be a number.